# cannot call function on navigation header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am not able to use ComponentDidMount to call function from the navigation options.

I have implemented the suggested way of calling a function using getparam.

```
export default class ExpandableCalendarScreen extends PureComponent {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: "My Calendar",
      headerRight: (
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.getParam('handleSave')}
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      )
    };
  };
```

```
  Show = () => {
    console.log("Here");
  };
```

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: this.Show });
  }
...............
}
```

I expect to see "here" in the console

Comment: You need to call the function. `navigation.getParam` only obtains the value in the param which points to a function. You need to execute it, maybe like `onPress={() => navigation.getParam('handleSave')()}`

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I can now sleep peacefully. :)